# When exactly does Mongoid actually make a query to MongoDb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am having difficulty finding documentation that clearly states at what point Mongoid actually queries against a Mongo Database.

Say I have a model called Projects, which references another model called Website as follows

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...

  has_one :website
  ...

end

class Website
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  belongs_to :project
  ...

end
```

If withing my Project model, I have a number of methods which access properties of the Website object, my question is, which line does the actual query to the Mongodb occur:

```
class Project      
  ...
  def website_url
    @website ||= self.website #Does the query occur here?

    website.url # Or does is occur here?
  end
```

I can foresee situations where putting off querying the database until an actual property or attribute of the object was requested being quite beneficial. However, I am not sure how to test this to determine the answer for myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add logging to your application (Moped being the underlying Mongoid driver for Mongoid):

```
Moped.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
Moped.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
```

You'll see that depending on configuration, the property retrieval of the referenced document may be delayed until first needed.

For example, with two classes like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  belongs_to :band
end

class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :popularity, type: Integer

  has_many :users    
end
```

Then used like:

```
def find_user
    query = User.where(:name => 'Johnny')
    user = query.first  # just the first

    puts "Just the user"
    puts user.band.name
end
```

You might end up with results like this:

```
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (2.0020ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 INSERT       database=mm collection=users documents=[{"_id"=>"528ebd08cbafedb879000001", "name"=>"Johnny"}] flags=[] (0.0000ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 INSERT       database=mm collection=bands documents=[{"_id"=>"528ebd08cbafedb879000002", "name"=>"StackOverflowTo11", "popularity"=>10}] flags=[] (1.0011ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=mm collection=users selector={"_id"=>"528ebd08cbafedb879000001"} update={"$set"=>{"band_id"=>"528ebd08cbafedb879000002"}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mm collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"name"=>"Johnny"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (2.0020ms)
Just the user
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mm collection=bands selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"528eb8f3cbafed9682000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (16.0160ms)
StackOverflowTo11
```

If you enable the [Identity Map](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html) feature and the `includes` function call, the relationships are retrieved immediately (or retrieved from a cache).